# Install features in multiple MSi in WiX

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I am working on developing Windows installer for an enterprise product, that has different variants  as separate MSI products. We have to check that, we cannot install a product, if another variant is installed already. I created different WIX scripts and used to build them as separate products (MSI).

Each variant has a base framework, and number of modules. I created each module as a feature, and included them along with base feature (base feature must be installed as of now) based on the variant built.

I received requirements that, we have to allow installing another variant on top of any installed variant. For Example, I installed Product1 that has 2 modules along with base framework as three features (Base, Mod1, Mod2). Product2 built with Base and Mod3. Now, When I install Product2 in a system where Product1 is installed, only the Mod3 should be installed.

I am using WIX 3.5.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without testing, I would say you can do this with [`ComponentSearch`](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/util_xsd_componentsearch.htm). Define such search, search for a component of product 1 and write the result to a variable. You can then check if the variable is not empty to determine if product 1 is already installed.

```
 <Property Id="EXISTING_PRODUCT">
      <ComponentSearch Id="SearchMyProduct" Guid="{YOUR-OWN-GUID}" Type="file"/>
</Property>
```

Then you can use a [`Condition`](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix2/wix_xsd_condition.htm) in the Feature.

```
<Feature Title="Product2">
    <Condition Level="0">EXISTING_PRODUCT <> ""</Condition>
</Feature>
```

You can also use a CustomAction to define the desired value based on search result to disable the [`Feature`](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix2/wix_xsd_feature.htm). (Should be a value for Level).

I haven't tested this way, but I think it should work. Have a try and give feedback please.

Additional Link:

http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial/getting-started/conditional-installation

Comment: Thank you Martin.  Let me check this with my WIX Project.

Comment: This is worked for me. But I have to compromise my custom actions. I am re-writing my custom actions for Install and Uninstall.  Accepted the answer.

Comment: I had to use Property@Secure="yes" for the uninstall to handle the condition correctly. Otherwise the property is ignored on uninstall.